# Is scala reference comparison similar to c++ pointers?

Tags: scala, reference, comparison

Can I test equality of two objects using `=` on their references? I mean do references behave like **c++ pointers** (in matter of comparison)?

Example - can I be assured that each object of `ll` list is printed **once and only once**?

```
val ll: List[MyObject] = // definition of list of my very complicated objects

for (x <- ll) {
    for (y <- ll) {
        if (x == y) println(x)
    }
}
```

I guess comparison on **same** object fails if the **references** are different (if having different references on same object is even possible).

Does this behavior change if the list is passed as an argument to some method?

Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In scala, `==` and `equals` are equivalent except that `==` handles `null`.

To check the reference, you must use the `eq` function from [`AnyRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.AnyRef).